# Specific C# HWID Lock

Tags: c#, web

I would like to create a HWID lock for my software, however, unlike all of the other ones. I don't want it to run a form. What I would like there to be, is a console application that runs and displays your HWID , and then checks it to a file on my website. If the HWID is on the website, it runs the console application.

Comment: What's a HWID??

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @Plutonix 3 hours worth lol, im stumped here

Comment: @MickyD your computers unique id

Comment: Thats not even a start.  You want a hash not a number or a value

Comment: In our programs, we do use the serial number of the main Windows drive. Although this number _could_ be changed by the user, it is sufficient for our needs.